# How to run an executable file from root on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

My problem is fairly simple.

I have a file that I want to run, say `x.sh`.

From my root location I run something like.

```
$ cd  Desktop/./x.sh -args
```

It prompts me to go to the directory and then run the file.

And as prompted the following works

```
$ cd Desktop
$ ./x.sh -args
```

Now, Am I missing something here or is this just the way Ubuntu is designed to work?

Comment: Either use `Desktop/./x.sh -args` or use `cd Desktop/; ./x.sh -args`. These 2 are different w.r.t. script's working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `cd` while executing a file. Directly execute it on the prompt: `Desktop/x.sh -args`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something. You can either cd to the directory and run the file from that directory or you can run the file from the absolute path or relative path, provided the user you're trying to run it with has access to that directory. The following should work at the level you were trying to do `cd Desktop/./x.sh -args`:

```
./Desktop/x.sh -args
```